# unexported struct best practice? (golint complains)

Tags: go

I have the following package :

```
package mypkg

type (
    // mystruct ...
    mystruct struct {
        S string
    }
)

// New ..
func New() *mystruct {
    return &mystruct{S: "test"}
}
```

I use it this way:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "test/mypkg"
)

func main() {
    x := mypkg.New()
    fmt.Println(x.S)
    // this fails intended
    y := mypkg.mystruct{S: "andre"}
    fmt.Println(y.S)
}
```

Why is golint complaining about my unexported struct? My intension is to prevent calling the struct creation outside the constructor call.
Is there another way to prevent instantiating without the New call?

Comment: What's the message/warning from golint?

Comment: I assume its because your calling an unexported struct from a different package `main` than the one it was defined in.  Basically it's saying remove the call or export the struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `x := mypkg.New()` in main.main() even can't have any type. It should not even compile. It's unusable. Seems to me more meaningful would be something like

```
package mypkg
type (
    // mystruct ...
    mystruct struct {
        S string
    }
)
type HaveS interface{ //which you can use but can't instantiate
    GetS() string
}
func (strct *mystruct ) GetS() string {return strct.S}
// New ..
func New() HaveS {
    return &mystruct{S: "test"}
}
```

then in main

```
var x mypkg.HaveS
x = mypkg.New()
fmt.Println(x.GetS())
```